# Framework iText gerando arquivo vazio (0 kb)

Tags: java, android, pdf

Eu tenho um projeto que estava gerando os PDFs normalmente, gerava os textos e imagens no arquivo, estava uma beleza, porém, um tempo depois ele deixou de forma inesperada de gerar o arquivo da forma correta, não importa o que eu faça ele sempre vai gerar o PDF com 0kb, completamente vazio, não mexi na classe e este apareceu, confesso que não entendo, já o retirei do Gradle e coloquei de novo, já criei um novo projeto só para fazer o teste deste framework e nada de se resolver, será que o problema é no Android Studio? Ele ta me pedindo para atualizar para versão 1.2.1.1 ou será o framework????

Irei mandar uma classe do meu projeto de teste, é muito simples:

```
 public class TestePDF {

public void gerar() {
    String pathPdf = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Teste PDF/Notificações Teste/";

    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
    try{
        File dir = new File(pathPdf);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(dir, "Teste.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        document.open();
        Font bold = FontFactory.getFont("Times-Roman, Bold", 12, Font.BOLD);
        Paragraph p00 = new Paragraph("Teste Bold", bold);
        Paragraph p01 = new Paragraph("Teste sem bold");
        p00.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
        p01.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
        document.add(p00);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        document.add(p01);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        document.close();
        Log.i("PDF", pathPdf);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Erro PDF", e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Mesmo assim, só gera arquivo com 0 kb.

GRADLE:

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.0.6'
```

Answer (score 0):

Bem galera, problema resolvido, espero que seja útil para alguém, no meu projeto, eu devo ter apagado uma linha, pesquisei e notei a falta:

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fOut);
```

preciso adicionar antes desta linha:

```
document.open();
```